# Passing route from laravel blade to vue component causing duplicate output

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am passing 6 routes from a blade file to a Vue component but when I do and output the routes, the 6 routes appear 6 times in groups of 6. Each group of the same 6 routes shows as it's own component in the vue dev tools.

index.blade.php (some of the looping is done in blade)

```
 @foreach (App\Questions::all() as $question)
    <question
        :questions="{{App\Questions::all()}}"
        :user="{{$user}}"     
        routes="{{route($question->route)}}">  //Passing the 6 question routes
    </question>
 @endforeach
```

Questions.vue

```
 <div v-for="question in questions">
    <div v-for="route in routes">
          <a :href="route">
            {{ question.title }}
          </a>
     </div>
 </div>


<script>
export default {
    props: ["questions", "user", "routes"];
}
</script>
```

Why are they showing up as 6 different components, each component with the same information 6 times.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop six times, creating six components here:

```
 @foreach (App\Questions::all() as $question)
```

You bind the same questions, to each component by getting all question models.

```
:questions="{{App\Questions::all()}}"
```

Try binding instead to:

```
 :questions="{{ $question }}"
```

Comment: So do I onlt need to bind to ``` :questions="{{ $question }}"``` and I can remove the ```user``` and ```routes``` bindings?

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, I did not have to use the ```v-for``` in my vue component since I was already looping in the blade file. I also did pass through ```$question``` as well as ```routes``` and ```user``` as bound attributes. Thank you @Bennett